# Apparent Mismatch Between Tango Core and OTA Version

Tags: google-project-tango

It appears that a large fraction of Tango users are experiencing issues since Leibniz was pushed out.  I found this post in another thread and thought it might be why I am seeing so much instability in my app after the update:

This is from: [TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable() gets stuck or crashes using Google Tango Leibniz Release 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750241/tangoservice-connectonframeavailable-gets-stuck-or-crashes-using-google-tango)

"Apologies, that you are experiencing problems. Is this still happening? I am asking this because, there was a bit of leeway in timing between when the TangoCore was updated on PlayStore and when the OTA went out (which can potentially cause this issue, if OTA and TangoCore are mismatched). I just want to make sure that you are are updated on both TangoCore and OTA before diagnosing it. Also, make sure you have permissions for camera in the android manifestl." –  r4ravi2008

I am pretty sure that the reason I am having problems is because I do have the mismatch described above.  I have Tango Core updated through Google Play, but if I got to "About Tablet" I see:

Build number: KOT49H.150320
Also, my Kernel version has an updated date of Friday March 20th.

This build number is exactly the build number referenced here: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/depth-test

However, on this page it says that this build is for Kalman (not Leibniz). When I try the suggested step of going to "System Updates" and clicking "Check for Update" the system says that it is up to date (even though apparently it did not receive the latest OTA).

Two questions:

1. Am I correct in that Kernel (OTA) and project tango core are mismatched?
2. If so, how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you send over your device's serial number to project-tango-help@google.com. The help team should help resolve your issue of not getting an OTA.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance as this is rather a comment than an answer to  Voxel Scanner Voxxlr's post... But as I don't have 50 reputation points I cannot leave comments...

Well, like Mark I reset the device to factory settings and *carefully* updated everything (PlayStore, System Update)... Then, I made *super* sure that the correct tango_client_api.h/.so is used in my project... Et voila, suddenly it worked... Generally, it seems to be a good idea to spend as little time in the callbacks as possible... Otherwise you can observe these "hiccups" Mark is reporting... After considerable rearrangements in my code everything runs smoothly again... I can also confirm that the color frames are OK... If you are interested in my converter code: I posted it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750241/tangoservice-connectonframeavailable-gets-stuck-or-crashes-using-google-tango)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a blunt instrument -  force the Tango to do a full factory reset and let it start all over again-  I can say that Explorer seems to work fine and the unity pointcloud and tracking samples work, but I'm just getting started and absolutely nothing in this statement should be misconstrued as an endorsement - remember, YMMV  :-)

Yeah, no.  The Unity Point Cloud sample hiccups all the time with respect to displaying point clouds, and crashes after a minute or two  :-(

Comment: I tried this as well, however, upon factory restart I still had the problem of not having a new version of the Tango kernel.  The system was still very unstable even when running Tango Explorer (pose tracking constantly being lost, tablet randomly reboots, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, I had similar problems where point cloud and motion tracking would get lost every couple seconds and eventually the app would crash. But just yesterday, my device said there was an update, while previous manual system checks kept saying it was up to date. After updating, the build number lists KOT49H.150414 (Kernel date is April 14, 2015), so that seems to be the actual Leibniz release on the device (not just the Core and SDK), and things are much more stable now.

Also just got the color data and displaying it like an AR image, but it's still in YUV format so everything is red. Working on converting it to RGB, but things seem to be working much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this technically qualifies as an answer, but I received this message from Google tango support:

Hi there,

What you are experiencing is a known bug that we have found fix too. Please stay tuned to our next OTA update that will fix this issue. We hope to push this update as soon as possible and thanks for your patience.

Best,

Monty

Project Tango Support

I am honestly not quite sure how to interpret this.  What exactly is the bug?  That my device won't download the latest OTA?  Based on Brian's post, it really does seem that I have a mismatch between Tango Core and the kernel that needs to be remedied to get acceptable performance.

Answer (score 0):

See [Google+ Tango Page](https://plus.google.com/107000393284585119717/posts/Q9etEwrWWrs) for info on the issue - there was an OTA update issue - it is being corrected