# OTA and kernel mismatch

Tags: google-project-tango

I am still confused about whether my device is properly updated, or whether Leibnitz has a problem, or something else is wrong ?

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750241/tangoservice-connectonframeavailable-gets-stuck-or-crashes-using-google-tango) r4ravi2008, who appears to be a Tango dev said:

> Apologies, that you are experiencing problems. Is this still
>   happening? I am asking this because, there was a bit of leeway in
>   timing  between when the TangoCore was updated on PlayStore and when
>   the OTA went out (which can potentially cause this issue, if OTA and
>   TangoCore are  mismatched). I just want to make sure that you are are
>   updated on both TangoCore and OTA before diagnosing it. Also, make
>   sure you have  permissions for camera in the android manifestl.

Could you please clarify with actual version numbers how one can tell if that mismatch is indeed the case. For example, in my device under Settings->About Tablet it says:

```
Kernel Verison 
3.10.24-gcde7bc7
Tango@Atap #1
Fri Mar 20 10:12:09 GMT 2015

Build Number
KOT49H.150320
```

Next, under About in the Project Tango Explorer it says:

App Version 1.11
Tango Service Version 1.11

Is this combination of OTA Tango Core/Firmware/Kernel/whatever correct? If so, then the Tango Explorer keeps loosing pose data every few seconds 
and eventually crashes; either, my device is broken, Tango Explorer has a problem or Leibnitz has a problem.

If the above is not the correct combination, then how can I fix it? In previous posts some people said that going back to factory reset and updating everything fixed the problem; others say it didn't? Please include in the answer what I am supposed to see in the above text fields so that I can be certain that my device is in the right state. Thank you.

Comment: You need the version of the Project Tango Core.  Go to Settings -> Apps -> Project Tango Core.  The top line will give the version of the Tango service code that running on your tablet, with a date and a name (i.e. Jacobi, Kalman, Leibniz).  This just tells you what you have.  I can't tell you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I received my tablet on Wednesday the 22nd. I jumped right in without downloading everything in the proper order. I tried to download the core before updating the tablet. Then after updating the tablet it refused to let me download the proper version of the core. Every demo I tried would track for 2-5 seconds and then suddenly crash. Restarting the apps would say that the service was unavailable, and restarting the tablet would give me another few seconds of tracking before suddenly crashing again.

So on Thursday the 23rd I did a factory reset. Updated the tablet first through system preferences. After that I downloaded the core through the play store. Then downloaded explorer and several demos. Everything works fantastically and I haven't had a crash since.

These are the versions I have:

Kernel Version
3.10.24-g36a1dd3
Tango@Atap #1
Tue Apr 14 11:34:37 BST 2015

Build number
KOT49H.150414

Project Tango Explorer

App version 1.11
Tango service version 1.11

Hope that helps!